# android 9 patch drawable xml

Tags: android, xml, drawable, nine-patch

Is there a way to define a 9 patch drawable in an android xml file?  The reason I ask, is that when you apply a scale animation to a drawable w/ a stroke on it, the stroke appears to thicken.  I'd like to make the stroke stay the same size as the animation plays...

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- so you want to bake the stroke into the 9-patch?

Answer (score 18):

Yes, but this is done mostly to define dithering for the 9-patch.
Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nine-patch
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable_here"
        android:dither="true"
        >
</nine-patch>
```

For more information see [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: like the answer.  like the name.